# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Audit Problems

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a current audit in MS sql server 2012 that is set up with the following audit properties:

```
queue delay : 1000 milliseconds
on audit level failure: continue
audit destination:  file
file path C:\STIGAudit
audit file maximum length : maximum rollover file selected with maximum number of files = 5000
maximum file size: 2MB
reserve disk space: checked
```

The audit when enabled writes 2MB files until the folder reaches 100MB size and then it writes only 0KB files to the folder. Why is it writing empty files after 100MB? Shouldn't it be writing files until it reaches approx. 10GB? The audit was disabled while these values were input and then renabled afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem quite right, perhaps something on that screen is buggy. To ask the obvious: the disk has plenty of space, right? Does it still cap at 100MB if you switch to "max rollover files: unlimited" (just for testing)? You could also try unchecking "Reserve disk space", I can't seem to find any good documentation on what exactly that does (or more precisely, *how* exactly it "reserves" the disk space).